# ¿Cómo importar un archivo de Google Drive en un cuaderno de Google Colaboratory?

Tags: python, jupyter, google-drive, importación, ipython

En un ipython notebook de Google Colaboratory quiero utilizar [un archivo](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fusGaCn-kXkmoR56qG7evOQa-RKV__wN/view?usp=sharing) que esta en mi Google Drive. Aprendí de [allí](https://colab.research.google.com/notebooks/io.ipynb#scrollTo=zU5b6dlRwUQk) que tengo que obtener la identificación del documento. Sin embargo, no puedo encontrarlo en Drive. ¿Sabes cómo puedo encontrarlo?

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

# 1. Authenticate and create the PyDrive client.
auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

# PyDrive reference:
# https://gsuitedevs.github.io/PyDrive/docs/build/html/index.html

# How do I import the file now?
file = drive.CreateFile({'id': uploaded.get('id')})
```

Answer (score 2):

El `id` puedes verlo cuando obtienes un enlace para compartir.

En tu caso ya estás compartiendo el fichero a través del enlace que has puesto en tu pregunta, que es:

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1fusGaCn-kXkmoR56qG7evOQa-RKV__wN/view?usp=sharing
```

La parte entre el `d/` y el `/view` es el id.

Puedes descargarlo en un libro de Collaboratory con el siguiente código, que he tomado de la documentación del sitio, pero he cambiado para que no intente mostrar por pantalla el contenido del fichero descargado, sino sólo su longitud, ya que en este caso el fichero es tan grande que volcarlo en una celda traería problemas:

```
from pydrive.auth import GoogleAuth
from pydrive.drive import GoogleDrive
from google.colab import auth
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials

# 1. Authenticate and create the PyDrive client.
auth.authenticate_user()
gauth = GoogleAuth()
gauth.credentials = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
drive = GoogleDrive(gauth)

# PyDrive reference:
# https://gsuitedevs.github.io/PyDrive/docs/build/html/index.html

# How do I import the file now?
downloaded = drive.CreateFile({'id': file_id})
contenido = downloaded.GetContentString()
print("Descargados {} bytes".format(len(contenido)))
```

El contenido del fichero está en la variable `contenido`, por lo que puedes guardarlo en disco (el disco de la máquina virtual en que se ejecuta el Notebook) así:

```
with open("mi_fichero.json", "w") as f:
    f.write(contenido)
```

Ten cuenta no obstante que tras un periodo de inactividad, Google apagará la máquina virtual en que se ejecuta el libro. La próxima vez que intentes usarlo el fichero descargado ya no estará ahí, pero lo obtienes de nuevo volviendo a ejecutar la celda que lo descargó.

Comment: Desafortunadamente tengo un `SyntaxError: invalid syntax` con `downloaded = drive.CreateFile({'id': 1fusGaCn-kXkmoR56qG7evOQa-RKV__wN})`

Comment: @Marine1 El ID tiene que ir entre comillas, claro.  Olvidé en el ejemplo anterior la asignación `file_id = "1fusGaCn-kXkmoR56qG7evOQa-RKV__wN"`