# Tengo script que funciona perfecto excepto por el adjunto (attachments) que no se envía

Tags: email, google-apps-script, google-drive

Les dejo el script que he creado para una junta de condominio de vivienda donde soy el presidente y quiero automatizar el proceso de pagos y envío de recibos de ingresos.
No encuentro cómo tomar el PDF que acabo de guardar en G. Drive y enviarlo como un adjunto.
Coloco únicamente la parte del script que guarda como PDF en G. Drive y la parte que envía el email.

```
    //Guardo la factura en Drive como un pdf 
     var blob = DriveApp.getFileById("1IRD8a76SVU1leDEtRqdLgSCbAn1xlHBpOgl9fZ4PEq8").getAs("application/pdf");//La Hoja que se convertira a pdf
     var name = datoshoja1[i][1];//Toma el registro como el nombre para el pdf
           blob.setName(name);//Da nombre al pdf
     var carpeta = DriveApp.getFolderById("1s6jiCNNNBgwXlh8rWXAKC3W5mzOsXyKq");//Carpeta G. Drive destino donde se guardará el pdf
         carpeta.createFile(blob);//Esto crea el pdf en la carpeta destino

  //Enviar la Factura creada y guardada en G. Drive por email
          var obtenerpdf = carpeta.getFilesByName();
          var email = datoshoja1[i][3];
          var nombre = datoshoja1[i][4];
          var casa = datoshoja1[i][5];
          var mensajetemporal = datoshoja1[i][2]; 
          var total = datoshoja1[i][9];
          var recibo = datoshoja1[i][1];
          var sujeto = "Recibo de Ingreso del Sr(a):" + nombre

          // emailBody es para los equipos que no pueden leer HTML, es el texto
          var emailBody = "Este es un correo con el RECIBO DE INGRESO del Sr(a). " + nombre + 
                    "\nde la casa " + casa + 
                    "\ndel correo " + email + 
                    "\nPago recibido el " + mensajetemporal +
                    "\nTotal pagado de Bs. " + total +
                    "\nN° de Recibo:  "+ recibo +
                    "\n\nGracias por su pago."; 

         // html es para los equipos que pueden leer HTML
         // Hoy en día casi todos los equipos pueden leer HTML
         var htmlBody =  "RECIBO DE INGRESO" + 
                    "<br/><br/>SE INCLUYE EL RECIBO COMO UN ADJUNTO " + 
                    "<br/>Nombre: <font color=\"red\"><strong>" + nombre + "</strong></font>" +
                    "<br/>de la casa: " + casa +  
                    "<br/>del correo: " + email +
                     "<br/>Total Pagado de Bs.: " + total +
                     "<br/>N° de Recibo: " + recibo;

           // Estas instrucciones para enviar el correo: 

                  //Parametros de opciones avanzadas
            var advancedOpts = { name: "Tesorería A.C. El Cardenal", htmlBody: htmlBody, attachements: [obtenerpdf]};
                 //Se envía el correo
            MailApp.sendEmail(email, sujeto, emailBody, advancedOpts);
```

Espero puedan ayudarme con esto, si necesitan todo el script me dicen y se los paso.

Comment: Bienvenido a SOes, te invito a realizar el [tour] así conoces un poco mas el sitio y ademas obtienes tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)

Comment: Hola, esta linea: `var obtenerpdf = carpeta.getByName();`. Ese método no existe en la [Clase Folder de DriveApp](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/folder). Tal vez `getFilesByName()` es lo que tratas de usar. Verifica eso y comentas, luego verificamos otro posible error cuando pasas el argumento a `attachments`.

Comment: Gracias Mauricio Contreras por tu corrección, no me había dado cuenta de ese error.  Sin embargo sigo con el problema que no me envía el attachment, parece ser que no logra capturar el archivo que  acabo de guardar en Drive o, no se que otra cosa está causando este ´problema.   Si puedes ayudarme te lo agradezco.

Comment: El código de la pregunta no está completo. Por favor lee [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En la línea

```
var obtenerpdf = carpeta.getFilesByName()
```

falta especificar el nombre del archivo. Ref. [getFilesByName(name)](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/drive-app#getfilesbynamename)

Nótese que este método devuelve un objeto [FileIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator) y no un objeto [File](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file). Para tomar este, el código debe iterar a través de los miembros del objeto FileIterator.

Adaptación del ejemplo de la documentación oficial tomado del enlace previo (básicamente traducir el comentario).

```
// Registra el nombre de cada archivo en Mi Unidad del usuario.
var files = DriveApp.getFiles();
while (files.hasNext()) {
  var file = files.next();
  Logger.log(file.getName());
}
```

Por otro lado, el objeto File no se puede enviar directamente, a partir de este hay que crear un objeto [Blob](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/blob). A continuación una adaptación de ejemplo de envío de archivo adjunto usando [sendEmail](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/mail/mail-app#sendemailrecipient-subject-body-options) (básicamente traducir el comentario y las cadenas).

```
// Enviar un email con dos archivos adjuntos, un archivo de Google Drive (como PDF) y un archivo HTML.
var file = DriveApp.getFileById('1234567890abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz');
var blob = Utilities.newBlob('Agrega aquí cualquier contenido HTML', 'text/html', 'mi_documento.html');
MailApp.sendEmail('mike@example.com', 'Ejemplo de archivo adjunto', 'Se incluyen dos archivos adjuntos.', {
    name: 'Envío automático de emails',
    attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF), blob]
});
```

Preguntas relacionadas sobre enviar correos con Google Apps Script:

- [¿Cómo enviar un correo de respuesta automática de un formulario?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/164885/65)

Preguntas relacionadas sobre cómo obtener el id de archivo:

- [¿Cómo importar un archivo de Google Drive en un cuaderno de Google Colaboratory?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/188064/65)

Artículos publicados por mí

- [Cómo obtener el key o id de una HCG](https://www.rubenrivera.mx/2018/08/key-id-hcg.html)

Comment: Gracias por tu respuesta Sr Ruben.  Me gustaría me explicara un poco más lo siguiemte; Qué sería la Id que está en var file = DriveApp.getFileById ;   también esto:  var blob = Utilities.newBlob('Agrega aquí cualquier contenido HTML', 'text/html', 'mi_documento.html'); Qué sería lo que va allí si ya tengo un body en html creado.   O sea si puedes explicarme mejor esta parte porque no la comprendo en relación a mi string.

Comment: Sobre el id agregué unos en enlaces que te podrían servir. Si sólo te interesa enviar un archivo, omite la línea `var blob = Utilities.newBlob('Agrega aquí cualquier contenido HTML', 'text/html', 'mi_documento.html')` en la línea `attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF), blob]` tendrías que quitar la `, blob`. Si recién estas iniciando a programar y has empezado con Google Apps Script, lee acerca de lo básico de JavaScript, como declaración de funciones y variables, tipos de datos, en particular Array. Conocer lo básico de JavaScript es fundamental.

Comment: Si la respuesta de @Rubén es satisfactoria no olvides marcarla como válida.

Comment: Gracias una vez más sr Ruben.  Le comento que coloqué var files = DriveApp.getFileById("1IRD8a76SVU1leDEtRqdLgSCbAn1xlHBpOgl9fZ4PEq8")    con el Id de la carpeta dónde está el pdf; pero cuando  va hacer while (files.hasNext())  me dice que no encuentra la función hasNext() en Recibos de Ingresos (es el nombre de la carpeta donde está el archivo pdf).  No entiendo esto.  Si puede ayudarme le agradezco una vez más.

Comment: @DougOliva lo que pasa es que `getFileById(id)` devuelve un objeto File, no un objeto Fileiterator. Mira con atención el segundo fragmento de código en mi respuesta.

Comment: Sr Ruben me da pena con usted pero, nunca había eviado un correo con un adjunto y estoy muy confundido y enredado.  Tengo esto: var blob = DriveApp.getFileById("1IRD8a76SVU1leDEtRqdLgSCbAn1xlHBpOgl9fZ4PEq8").getAs("application/pdf");
var name = datoshoja1[i][1]; blob.setName(name);
var carpeta = DriveApp.getFolderById("1s6jiCNNNBgwXlh8rWXAKC3W5mzOsXyKq");
carpeta.createFile(blob);//Esto crea el pdf en la carpeta destino  ¿Cómo tomo ese archivo pdf de Drive que guardé y lo envio por correo como un attachment? Si puede hacerlo le agradezco porque estoy confundido.

Comment: Sr Ruben LO LOGRÉ!!!!!!!    lo hice así:                     
      var file = blob;  //Ya blob lo había definido al guardar el pdf en Drive.
      MailApp.sendEmail(email, sujeto, emailBody, {
        name: "Tesorería A.C. El Cardenal",
        attachments: [file.getAs(MimeType.PDF)]
      });

Comment: @DougOliva Me da mucho gusto por ti, felicidades y gracias por compartirlo.